# Is std::list size() an O(1) or O(n) function call?

Tags: c++, list, stl, size, complexity-theory

I just wonder how expensive is it to call a std::list size(). Some people say it's an O(1) call because the size is updated upon insert() or remove()/erase(). Some people say it will iterate from begin to end and count how many elements are there.

Does c++ standard say anything about how the complexity of this function call should be?
Thanks!

Comment: [`std::list::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size)

Comment: Glad to see this got updated in C++11. Allowing `size()` to be linear was just to accommodate one particular implementation. Somewhere on the internet is a piece by the author of that implementation where he gives five spurious reasons why he's right and all the other implementations are wrong.

Comment: some people are right and some people have been right until c++11. Btw the draft versions of the standard are available online. You can read it.

Comment: For context, the only advantage to having linear `size` is that not storing the length makes splicing faster

Comment: @Jeffrey -- not storing the size makes the `list` object smaller, and in some realms that's important.

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container), a requirement for a class to be considered a `Container` is that the `size()` member function has constant complexity, i.e. `O(1)`, from `c++11` and onward.

One can also see that fact specifically for [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size) as @Quimby pointed out.